# CSS left text, centered image in table

Tags: css, center

I'm pretty new to CSS and cannot figure out how to accomplish the following.  I have tabular data.  Some of the data elements have images associated with them.  I want text in the cell left justified and I want the images in the same cell centered.

In other words, I want the same result as the following except inside a table cell.

```
<p>Some text.</p>
<img style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" src="myimage.jpg"/>
```

How can I accomplish this?  When I try placing this inside a td element, both the text and the image are at the left side.

Comment: Hmmm, may have answered my own question.  When I set the table to have width:100% it seems to accomplish the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use margin to center an element you need to have a set width:

```
<p style="text-align: left;">Some text.</p>
<img style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; width:200px;" src="myimage.jpg"/>
```

Also, consider putting your styles in an [external stylesheet](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) and use [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to target your elements.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to confirm what I discovered by forcing the table width to be the full page.  I do have my styles in an external stylesheet...the code above was just an abbreviated example of what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Gotcha, just wanted to make sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set your image to have absolute positioning, and it should work the way you want it. However, your text won't behave quite the way you think until you set a fixed width for your text element.